# strip and replace are not taking off "\n"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    a = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'title'})
    
    for e in a:
       
        e = str(e.text)
        e = e.replace(r"\n","")
        e = e.strip(r"\n")

        print(e)
```

currently it is printing
'\n\n                        Heavy Rain\n                        \n                    \n'

even after all the code I've tried without r before the \n and with r so I am not sure what else to do

Comment: What if you just do `e.strip()`?

Comment: If it is printing literal `\n`, it means that it is escaped, otherwise it would be whitespace you can easily `e.strip()`... You want to replace `\\n` instead.

Comment: try this new_str = my_string.rstrip(), rstrip will delete all trailing lines, this tuto is very helpful https://statisticsglobe.com/python-strip-remove-newline-from-string else, print a and see its output, maybe there is some work to do.

Comment: Can you maybe provide the output of response.text?

Comment: `r"\n"` is actually `"\\n"`.  Don't use `r`.

Answer (score 3):

the `r` before strings stands for raw. So your code searches for a backslash followed by an `n` to replace it with nothing.

You want to delete a newline, so you need non-raw text thus just remove those `r`